# How to move cursor focus right. left , up and down using arrow keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move focus right, left, up and down using arrow keys in JavaScript.

I am able to implement right functionality using JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
$(document).keydown(

    function(e)
    {    
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {      
            $(".tab:focus").prev().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 38) {      
            //code for up key   
        }
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {      
            $(".tab:focus").next().focus();

        }
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {      
            //code for down key
        }

    }
);
```